# Per-object Data in Allocators?

Tags: c++, stl

What is "Per-object Data in Allocators". I can't seem to find what this means. Anyone have a good explanation or link for what this means in terms of the C++ Language?

---

**CLARIFICATION**

Section 19.4.2 "The C++ Programming Language (Special Edition)"  pg. 573

"Similarly, if allocators were allowed to be perfectly general, the *rebind* mechanism that allows an allocator to allocate elements of arbitrary types would have to be more elaborate. Consequently, a standard allocator is assumed to hold no per-object data and an implementation of a standard container may take advantage of that."

Comment: Where did you see the phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per-object data or local state refers to any non-static data members in the allocator class.

The issue is that currently (in `c++03`) there is no support for allocators with so-called local state. This is often considered to be a flaw with the allocator model in present-day `c++`.

Have a read through [this](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184406243) article that details the design for a custom allocator. A paragraph under *Design* specifically addresses some of the pitfalls of allocators that incorporate local state.

Briefly, some operations in the standard library currently require that objects of a particular type be safely allocated by one instance of an allocator and deallocated by another instance of the allocator (both allocators are of the same type - of course!). This can be the case when implementing `list::splice` for instance. If allocators are allowed to have local state this can get tricky...

In the upcoming `c++0x` revision, it appears that allocators will be allowed to incorporate local state, check out the *scoped allocator* section [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#scoped-allocator).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that `std::allocator<T>` does not contain any per-instance data members ... it is mainly a wrapper around memory allocation and deallocation functions, and also contains definitions of certain required typedefs, as well as mechanisms for rebinding an existing allocator so that it can allocate types that were not part of the original allocator template instantiation.  So basically what is being stated is that if there were actual private data-members that had to be managed, especially in light of the requirement for a STL allocator to allow rebinding, that could greatly complicate the implementation of a generic allocator depending on what those per-instance data-members represented.